# 2D Array of References to Arrays

Tags: perl, reference, multidimensional-array

I am trying to understand how references work in Perl and have this example code I am trying to make work:

```
my @name = ("Jack S", "John L", "Cary S");
my @number = ("29", "78", "54");
my @bigNumber = ("40000", "50000", "60000");

my @array2D = (\@name, \@number, \@bigNumber);
```

I am trying to print from this 2d array so it ends up with an output similar to this for each row in the array:

> Jack S  29  40000

I cant seem to wrap my head around the referencing part.

Comment: It would help to show what you tried to print it out

Comment: I think [`perldoc perllol`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html) is a must-read if you haven't done so already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good way to help understand what deep structures look like in Perl is to use [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper). For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @name = ("Jack S", "John L", "Cary S");
my @number = ("29", "78", "54");
my @bigNumber = ("40000", "50000", "60000");

my @array2D = (\@name, \@number, \@bigNumber);

print Dumper \@array2D;
```

That shows us this output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'Jack S',
            'John L',
            'Cary S'
          ],
          [
            '29',
            '78',
            '54'
          ],
          [
            '40000',
            '50000',
            '60000'
          ]
        ];
```

In other words, we passed `Dumper` a reference to an array which contains three items, each one of which is an array reference.

So if we want to loop over these arrays and print the items in the first slot of each, we could do this:

```
foreach my $ref( @array2D ) { 
    print $ref->[0], " ";
}
print "\n";
```

And that would output:

```
Jack S 29 40000
```

If you want to generalize that to print all the records, you could do something like this. (This assumes that all of your nested arrays are the same size as the first one.)

```
my $count = @{ $array2D[0] };
foreach my $index( 0 .. $count - 1) { 
    foreach my $ref( @array2D ) { 
        print $ref->[$index], " ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Jack S 29 40000
John L 78 50000
Cary S 54 60000
```

Although at this point, it might be better to rethink your structure. For example, maybe you want a hash of arrays indexed by name.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the response. Data Dumper makes it simpler to see the structure and understand the format of whats happening.

Comment: @TomGorski: You may be interested in the more recent [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump). It is written by Gisle Aas, author of the awesome LWP library and associated HTML modules. It produces much more readable data, and it exports `dd` by default so the syntax is just `dd \@array2D`. You will probably need to install it as it isn't part of core Perl.

Answer (score 2):

An array element is a scalar value. So that

```
$array[0]
```

Is always a single item. In your case, each element of `@array2D` contains a reference -- which is a scalar value. An address in memory.

```
$array2D[0]   # this is \@name, printed it looks like ARRAY(0x328c48)
```

To access a value in an array reference, there are two ways.

```
my $aref = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ];  # [ .. ] creates an anonymous array ref
print $$aref[0];                     # prints "foo"
print $aref->[0];                    # same thing
```

Now when you access an array ref in an array, you follow the same logic, albeit it is slightly more complicated

```
$array[0]           # this is an array ref, like $aref above
$array[0]->[0]      # using the arrow notation we can access the first element
$array[0][0]        # arrows between [], {} are optional, so we can remove it
```

If you want to access the entire array, you apply an array sigil to the reference, like this:

```
my @foo = @$aref    # @foo is now contains a copy of the elements
```

But when you have a multi-dimensional array, you cannot just do

```
@$array[0]          # wrong!
```

Because a subscript `[0]` has lower precedence than the sigil. So you need to use support curly braces

```
my @foo = @{ $array[0] }
```

Note that you use `@` to access an array, and `$` to access a scalar value.